# Is there a way to implement a voting system in the bug work item within TFS 2012

Tags: tfs

Our business users would like the ability to vote on bugs that should be included in our product backlog.  We are using the MSF Agile template and would need to update it to include the ability to vote on a bug work item.

This feature does need to be very user friendly as we are still early users for TFS 2012.

Comment: You may be able to create your own custom controls and custom work item fields to go with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the item templates in TFS, but I do not think that you can implement a voting system as you have described.